# OpenSL Tutorial ES for PC (Not Android)

Tags: android, c++, linux, audio, opensl

I'm looking to start learning the basics of OpenSL ES without getting into the whole Android business. Is there no tutorials describing the process of setting up OpenSL, as there are for OpenAL?

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES stands for Embedded Systems, so it's mst likely targeting mobile devices, not so much desktop PC's.

So its is not generally available for Desktop machines (OpenSL ES -  Embedded Audio Acceleration). : http://www.khronos.org/opensles/

Comment: This was what I expected to hear. This saddens me, because the OpenSL ES looks like it has a heck of alot of cool built in stuff like midi that something like OpenAL doesn't have. Is there not an OpenSL Non-ES version?